# Modify and add the remaining nested array to the next parent object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am basically creating a pdf page format in HTML. I have formatted the sections.
Page design is done.
What I'm stuck on is:

I have an array of sections and each section has an array of sub sections.
Each sub section contains details key which is an array of object. Code looks like:

```
sectionsDemo = [
  {
    sectionPrefix: 'A',
    sectionHeading: 'Section A: Description of Project Activity',
    subSections: [
      {
        heading: 'Purpose and General description of project activity',
        details: [
          {
            title: 'test A1 title',
            content: 'test A1 content',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
.
.
.
.

]
```

I want to make the sections array as such:

1. Traverse inside each section.
2. Iterate over section items.
3. Iterate details in each section item.
4. Calculate the content length.
5. If the content length exceeds the limit, say index I, truncate the content chars up to max limit.
6. Copy and insert the present details object, with the content being the chars after truncation, into the next index of the details array.
7. Now, I want to copy the subsection item with the index of details arr with new content object.

So it would become like this.

```
sectionsDemo = [
  {
    sectionPrefix: 'A',
    sectionHeading: 'Section A: Description of Project Activity',
    subSections: [
      {
        heading: 'Purpose and General description of project activity',
        details: [
          {
            title: 'test A1 title',
            content: 'test A1 ',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        heading: 'Purpose and General description of project activity',
        details: [
          {
            title: 'test A1 title',
            content: 'content',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
 
.
.
.
.

]
```

I have this code with me.

```
sectionFormatter = (sections: any) => {
  let formattedSection: any = [...sections];
  formattedSection = sections.map((section: any) => {
    return {
      ...section,
      subSections: subSectionsFormatter(section.subSections)
    }
  })
  return formattedSection
}

subSectionsFormatter = (data: any) => {
  // ** [subSections] ->[{ [details]}]-> {content, title}

  const subSections = [...data] //subsections array

  let formattedSubSections2: any = []

  for (let i = 0; i < subSections.length; i++) {
  
      const detailsArr = subSections[i].details
      if (detailsArr?.length){
        let CPCC = 0 // current page character count
        for (let j = 0; j < detailsArr.length; j++) {
          console.log('subSections[i] 44', subSections[i], data)
          const content = detailsArr[j].content
          if (content) {
            const CICC = content?.length || 0; // current item character count
             
            CPCC += CICC // sum of present chars and previously added chars
            if (CPCC > MAX_CHARS_PER_PAGE && content) {
              const LEFT_CHARS = CPCC - MAX_CHARS_PER_PAGE
              
              detailsArr[j].content = content?.slice(0, CICC - LEFT_CHARS)
              
              const newSubSection = {
                ...subSections[i],
                details:[...detailsArr.slice(0, j),{...subSections[i].details[j], content: content?.slice(CICC - LEFT_CHARS)} ]
              } 
            
              const arr: any = [subSections[i]].concat(([...subSections.slice(0, i ), newSubSection]))
             
              formattedSubSections2 = (formattedSubSections2.concat([...arr]))
              CPCC = 0
              break
            }
             else {
              formattedSubSections2.push(subSections[i])
            }
          }
        }}

     
    }

  return formattedSubSections2
}
```

It is not working as expected.
It's giving sub section array with content upto max limit.

Need community's help here. Any suggestions and help are welcome.

Codsandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-http-wcqjsk?file=/src/index.ts:0-15871

Comment: Hello, you're not really using Typescript here, as you have _any_ types everywhere. A good start to solve your problem would be to type your objects, by using [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). It will force you to understand what data you manipulate at each step of your code.

Comment: What is not working here? https://jsfiddle.net/codething/58e93sm0/9/

Comment: @CodeThing https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-http-wcqjsk?file=/src/index.ts:0-15871